# Loop taking too much time in R?

Tags: r

**Background:**

Find the number of times companies move in tandem regarding their Market Capitalization, so for example with company A and company B, they move 3 times together and I would like to divide it when both company A and B show values different than NA (here, 10). I used a logical formula, TRUE when they have the same letter, FALSE when they do not have the same letter and NA when there is one NA value in A or B.

**THE PROBLEM IS:**

**The code I used works with small sets, max 50 companies, then it takes too much time, and I am looking to do it for sets of 100 companies, approxi. 324.000.000 data points**

**Input (small subset): Dataframe "dat"**

```
           CompA CompB CompC CompD 
    1         A    F <NA>    A
    2         A    F <NA>    F
    3         F    E <NA>    A
    4         A    A <NA>    A
    5         F    A <NA>    F
    6         A    D <NA>    D
    7         F    F <NA>    B
    8         A    A <NA>    F
    9         F    E <NA>    F
    10       <NA>  C <NA>    A
    11        E    F <NA>    E
```

**Code used:**

```
  v <- NULL
  i <- 1
  j <- 1

  for(i in 1:length(dat)-1){

  j <- i+1
    while(j <= length(dat)-1){
  str(dat)

       qone <- data.frame(qone = 
         (as.character(dat[,i+1])==as.character(dat[,j+1])))

     count1 <- length(which(qone == TRUE))/(length(which(qone == 
  TRUE))+length(which(qone == FALSE)))

    v <- append(v, count1)
   v <- data.frame(v)

   j <- j+1
   }}
```

**Final output:**

```
        x1     x2     x3    x4     x5    x6
    1   0.3    NA     0.5   NA    0.27   NA
```

**Second Final output:** 1 Nb TRUE 2 Nb FALSE

```
         x1     x2     x3    x4     x5    x6
    1     3    0       5     0      3     0
    2     7    0       6     0      8     0
```

Comment: You're growing object within loops which causes the problem. Take a look at these links to learn more: http://r-statistics.co/Strategies-To-Improve-And-Speedup-R-Code.html & http://www.dartistics.com/fast-r-code.html

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it @Tung

Comment: Quite a few things to speed up here; Tung's comment is excellent, but also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402528/append-data-frames-together-in-a-for-loop

Comment: See also: http://winvector.github.io/Accumulation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using loops in R is generally inefficient. Since you are growing the data frame inside the nested loop, it's going to slow down things heavily

Try the following approach :

```
library(data.table)
#Create the dummy data

companyData <- fread("~/test_data.csv",sep = "\t",na.strings = "<NA>")

#Two apply function to cross-over other columns over each column
v <- lapply(companyData, function(leftcomp) {
  lapply(companyData, function(rightcomp) {
    mean(leftcomp == rightcomp, na.rm = T)
  })})

#Unlist data to get n*n vector which has all the values
results <- unlist(v)

#Some logic to collect the required elements only.
l <- length(companyData)
a <- 1:(l*l)
b <- rep(seq(1,l*l,by = l+1),times = rep(l,times = l))

log_vec <- a > b
# 
# > log_vec
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

final_result <- results[log_vec]

# > final_result
# CompA.CompB CompA.CompC CompA.CompD CompB.CompC CompB.CompD CompC.CompD 
# 0.3000000         NaN   0.5000000         NaN   0.2727273         NaN
```

I tried to create a dummy data frame with ~200,000 rows and ~80 columns and run the above code, took nearly minute on an average laptop.

More information on the function used :

The first `lapply` takes each column of `companyData` and passes to second `lapply`. This column is compared with each column of `companyData` again.

`mean(leftcomp == rightcomp, na.rm = T)`
`leftcomp == rightcomp` gives a logical vector with `TRUE` wherever the companies are in tandem. It returns and `NA` when any of the columns are `NA`.

Now, `mean` of this logical vector after ignoring the `NA`s would give us the ratio. This works because `TRUE` is essentially 1 and `FALSE` is 0 in R.

Eg:

```
>log_vec
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA TRUE
```

`mean(log_vec,na.rm = T)` returns 2/5 = 0.4.

Now, you wanted to select the elements which were unique (CompA vs CompB but not CompB vs CompA).

For that,

If `l` is the number of companies you're looking at (say, 4), `a <- 1:(l*l)` creates an index of all the computations `lapply` did above.

```
> a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

`b` is a vector as below :

```
> b
 [1]  1  1  1  1  6  6  6  6 11 11 11 11 16 16 16 16

log_vec <- a > b

> log_vec
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This vector has `TRUE` for the elements you need to pick.

Hope, it's more clear now.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the value of `x5` in your sample outcome be 0.2727?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Dave ! Yes, I got the wrong data in the question sorry.. I get this error:  Error in Ops.factor(leftcomp, rightcomp) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: And I have one more question if you don't mind.. If I wanted to count the number of TRUE and FALSE for each company to see if they are statistically significant, I edited the question with the output I would be looking for @Dave

Comment: I will try to add more detail on the answer today evening.  Can you elaborate more on the statistical significance question? What's your hypothesis? Sorry, but I don't see any edits in the question or output.

Comment: Sorry it did not update.. By statistical significance I mean just counting the number of TRUE and FALSE for each company pair, for example for company A & B we have 3 TRUE and 7 FALSE