# R : df.list[[i]] deletes every first row from multiple dataframes when tried to combine by row

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I've this <20 table in one .csv file, in multiple columns. I able to separate each tables using:

```
d <- split(table.df, r)
```

and I able to transpose it to rows of two columns using code below:

```
for (i in 1:length(d)) { 
  
  df <- data.frame(d[i])
  
  new.df <- stack(df)

  df.list[[i]] <- new.df
}
```

The example of stack data (new.df) is structured as below:

```
values  ind
*    X2000.Day
15   X2000.Jan
17.5 X2000.Jan
0.5  X2000.Jan
```

```
*    X2001.Day
33.7 X2001.Jan
0    X2001.Jan
1.8  X2001.Jan
```

```
*    X2002.Day
0    X2002.Jan
0    X2002.Jan
0    X2002.Jan
```

I also remove row that contain "*" by using

```
new.df <- new.df[!(new,df$values=="*"),]
```

However, when I try to combine all new.df by row using code below, which I'm referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402528/append-data-frames-together-in-a-for-loop/29419402)

```
merge.row = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

the df.list[[i]] deletes every first row when the new year begins, , which looks like this:

```
values  ind
17.5 X2000.Jan
0.5  X2000.Jan
0    X2001.Jan
1.8  X2001.Jan
0    X2002.Jan
0    X2002.Jan
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong, and I'm hoping you guys can point out what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in your loop when you save `new.df` as a list element in `df.list[[i]]`.  Usually when you save elements to a list in a loop you need to initiate a blank list item.  Try changing your code like this:

```
df.list<-list()

for (i in 1:length(d)) { 
  
  df <- data.frame(d[i])
  
  new.df <- stack(df)

  df.list[[i]] <- new.df
}
```

Comment: Omg, I was very certain that I had included df.list <- list() in my script, but once you pointed it out, I double-checked it and discovered that I had completely overlooked it. And it definitely solved the problem I was having; thank you so much, Sean! Please have a wonderful day!